# Recursive search using yield, returning list of parents

Tags: c#, recursion, yield

I need to do a recursive search over a tree and as a result I would like an IEnumerable containing the parents between a specified root and a target node.

Example data:

```
- ROOT
    - A
        - B
            - C
            - D
        - E
            - F
            - G
    - H
        - I
            - J
            - K
```

Example results:

```
GetParentsToTarget(ROOT, K) == {ROOT, H, I, K}
GetParentsToTarget(A, G) == {A, E, G}
GetParentsToTarget(A, K) == {} //K is not a child of A
```

Simply, because I like the syntax, I wanted to use `yield`, performance is not an issue (trees are fairly small).

I ended up with this basic recursive-yield-pattern, but it results in a `StackOverflowException`:

```
    IEnumerable<Node> GetParentsToTarget(Node parent, Node target)
    {
        if (parent == target) yield return target;

        foreach (var child in parent.Nodes)
        {
            foreach (var result in GetParentsToTarget(child, target))
            {
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**: As many comments have suggested, a `Parent` property would help, but unfortunately in this case that isn't possible.

Comment: This becomes trivial if you can store a pointer to a node's parent. Is that an option here?

Comment: You won't get a stack-overflow unless your tree is _at least_ hundreds, maybe thousands, of nodes deep - but you said the "trees are fairly small" so my guess is `parent.Nodes` returns more than just its children? Do you have any cycles in the graph?

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducable example, including the definition of `Node` and the initialization of your sample data structure.

Comment: As for mitigations: 1: add an `Int32 depth` parameter which increments `+1` on every step-into `GetParentsToTarget` and throw or abort if it gets too high (say, over 10, based on your diagram). 2: Use [`RuntimeHelpers.EnsureSufficientExecutionStack()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.ensuresufficientexecutionstack) to preempt a `StackOverflowException`:

Comment: `if (parent == target) yield return target;` <-- when this happens, shouldn't you stop the search as you've found your target?

Comment: If the `Node` class has `Parent` property, then get the `target` node first then yield the parents in a while loop until you get `null` (the Parent of the `Root` node). `.Reverse()` in the caller to get them in order if you want.

Comment: Do you have a `Parent` property on each node, or must you search the tree from the root? A [mcve] would help, including the class definition of `Node`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is made somewhat more complicated by the fact that you want to return the results starting with the parent node downwards.

If you have a `Parent` property on each node, you don't need recursion as such. You can simply loop up to the matching parent node and save that in a list, then return the reversed list.

```cs
 static IEnumerable<Node> GetParentsToTarget(Node parent, Node target)
 {
     var nodes = new List<Node>();
     var thisParent = target;
     while (thisParent != null)
     {
         nodes.Add(thisParent);
         if(thisParent == parent)
         {
             return Enumerable.Reverse(nodes);
         }
         thisParent = thisParent.Parent;
     }
     return Enumerable.Empty<Node>();
 }
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m1H43n)

---

Otherwise, you need to break out of your recursion by checking if the enumeration actually yielded the `target`. You can do this by manually enumerating using `GetEnumerator` and `MoveNext`.

```cs
 static IEnumerable<Node> GetParentsToTarget(Node parent, Node target)
 {
     if (parent == target)
     {
         yield return target;
         yield break;  // do not recurse or loop further.
     }

     foreach (var child in parent.Nodes)
     {
         using (var enumer = GetParentsToTarget(child, target).GetEnumerator())
         {
             if(!enumer.MoveNext())  // bail out of this child and continue searching
                 continue;

             // Otherwise we got the target from the recursion.
             // Yield the parent first, then descendants.
             yield return parent;
             do
             {
                 yield return enumer.Current;
             }
             while (enumer.MoveNext());
         }
     }
 }
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vXqwZv)

Comment: a fiddle nicely played ;o)